# How to handle memory warning in automatic reference counting in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview

I am using arc in my application.In my application i had played YouTube Video in UIWebView and video url comes from database and i put that url in UITableViewCell and i got memory receive warning.My database record is 60.
Any one help me out.Thank you in advance

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];
    VideoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell =[[VideoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        [cell.lblVid_Name setText:[[arr_Video     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Video_Name"]];
    [cell.lblVid_Desc setText:[[arr_Video objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Video_Desc"]];

        NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[arr_Video objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Video_Link"]lastPathComponent]];

        NSString *youTubeVideoHTML =@"<html><head> <meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = \"%f\"/></head> <body style=\"margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"> <iframe width= \"%f\" height=\"%f\" src = \"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?showinfo=0\"frameborder=\"0\" hd=\"1\" allowfullscreen/>></iframe></div></body></html>";
        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML,cell.webView_Video.frame.size.width,cell.webView_Video.frame.size.width, cell.webView_Video.frame.size.height,url];


        [cell.webView_Video loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
        url=nil;
        youTubeVideoHTML=nil;
        html=nil;

}
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So 60 cells are created and each is going to load a video - won't this eat up a huge amount of memory? Don't you want to show the possible videos, then only load them when the user taps a cell? Then once the cell is offscreen release the video?

Answer (score 3):

you are using a lot of cells and not reusing cells:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];
VideoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

that's mean you are creating a cell for each row!

you should reuse cells that are out of screen, not creating again a new one

use just a CellIdentifier for all the cells, then manage the data of that call (change the internal values of the cell) but reuse an old cell.

if you can see just 10 cells on screen at any time, you should alloc/create just 10 cells objects, even if your array contains 60 or more objects, but you create 60 cells / objects!